# How to perform action on a integer placeholder in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

```
print('%s is (%d+10) years old' % ('Joe', 42))
```

Output: Joe is (42+10) years old

Expected output: Joe is 52 years old

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this with [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) in Python 3.6+.

```
name = "Joe"
age = 42
print(f'{name} is {age + 10} years old')
```

Answer (score 5):

String formatting insert values into a string. To operate on a value you should compute the value first and *then* insert/format it into the string.

```
print('%s is %d years old' % ('Joe', 42 + 10)
# or  if you really want to something like that (python 3.6+)
name = 'joe' 
age = 42
f'{name} is {age +10} years old'
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do arithmetic operations inside a string.

```
print('%s is (%d) years old' % ('Joe', 42+10))
```

Answer (score 3):

`F-strings` ([PEP 498 : Python V 3.6](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)) can handle your case better since `f-string` expression are evaluated at run time. For e.g:

```
name = 'Joe'
a, b = 42, 10
print(f'{name} is {a + b} years old')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the values inside the string which is wrong.

```
print('%s is %d years old' % ('Joe', 42+10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Three ways

```
print('%s is %d years old' % ('Joe', 42+10))
print('{0} is {1} years old'.format('Joe', 42+10))
name='Joe'
print(f'{name} is {42+10} years old')
```

Just some other ways to print

```
print(name,'is',(42+10),'years old')
print(eval("name + ' is ' + str(42+10) + ' years old'"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print('%s is (%d+10) years old' % ('Joe', 42)
name='joe'
age=42+10
print(f'{name} is {age} years old')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I am using **Template string** to perform this action using another approach.It’s a ***simpler and less powerful mechanism***.

The best time to use template strings is when you’re handling **formatted strings generated by users** of your program. Due to their reduced complexity, template strings are a safer choice.

Here is the example of template string:

```
>>>from string import Template
>>>name = 'Joe'
>>>age=42
>>>t = Template('$name is $age years old')
>>>t.substitute(name = name, age=age+10)
```

**output**

> 'Joe is 52 years old'